# Expand abbreviation automatically at beginning of line

Tags: line-breaking, typography, acronyms

According to an tradition in Spanish typesetting (Martinez de Sousa, MELE4), the abbreviation `etc.` should be fully expanded to `etcétera` when it appears at the beginning of the line [(Spanish page in Wikipedia)](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etc%C3%A9tera).

I guess this could be done, using LuaTeX; by retypesetting the paragraph after checking if the beginning of the line is `etc.`. I think that upper limit of iterations should be used (probably the times `etc.` appears in the paragraph) because a new typesetting could move the location of `etc.`.

(note: This practise is now not used because of this reflow of the text.)

My question: Is someone willing to fight this challenge?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Without luatex you can do this, although the space around the word doesn't stretch with other inter-word space on the line.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\setlength\textwidth{5cm}

\def\etc.{\discretionary{}{etcétera}{\hbox{ etc.}}}

\begin{document}

abc\etc. abc\etc. abc\etc. abc\etc. 
abc\etc. abc\etc. abc\etc. abc\etc. 
abc\etc. abc\etc. abc\etc. abc\etc. 


\end{document}
```

An alternative scheme that avoids freezing the space in the box inside the discretionary would be to use `...abc~\etc.` with a definition

```
\def\etc.{\discretionary{}{etcétera}{etc.}}
```

But that leaves the space from `~` at the end of the line before the linebreak, so is only really usable in raggedright settings.

Comment: Nice solution. It is even better in Spanish because `et cétera` is just one word `etcétera` and you can get rid of the space in the first `\hbox`. Is it possible to get rid of the first `\hbox` by not allowing hyphenation in the word `etcétera` (like an hyphenation exception)?

Comment: @zunbeltz no you have to have a hbox, if you try to put text in the \discretionary you get an error message saying only hbox and kern allowed

Comment: you only need the \hbox because of the space. If the material only consists of characters then that is enough so \discretionary{}{etcétera}{\hbox{ etc.}} should work too, but because of the space you need the \hbox in the third argument.

Comment: @FrankMittelbach yes that occurred to me later but I was driving to London so couldn't update, thanks for the correction:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I took out the space in the second \hbox and put a ~ before `\discretionary`. This give a slightly  different space between the words. The overfull box that arises in your example disappears; but I am not still sure which is better. Probably I should made a more realistic example; with more text, longer words and much fewer etcs.

Comment: @zunbeltz sorry that doesn't really work in general as it leaves the space from `~` at the linebreak. I updated my answer.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ok. This was happening to me but I did not understand. So, for now, this solution works _almost_ perfectly. The only problem seems to be that the space before the `etc.` is fixed size.